# k10temp Chip Temperature Threshold Adjustment

Tags: cpu, monitoring, temperature, adjustment

Is there any way to adjust the threshold of `k10temp Chip`

I am not sure is it possible or not,

My `sensors` output is below,

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:    +66.5 C (high = +90.0 C)

k10temp-pci-00cb
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:    +46.4 C (high = +70.0 C)
```

My requirement is to change  `high = +90.0 C` value only,
I am not sure is it possible or not.

I am using this command and it increases both Temp and Threshold

```
chip "k10temp-pci-00c3"
label temp2 "Core 0"
compute temp2 @-20,@-20
```